# grails rendering pdf plugin not working, simple example?

Tags: grails, controller, pdf-generation, rendering

I am trying to save a simple template to pdf using the rendering plugin, but I cannot get it to work no matter what I try.  All I need is for it to save a file within the file system on the server and redirect to a different page.

At the minute the pdf template does not need any parameters as it just prints hello world.  Once I get this working I will attempt to add some data.

I am getting errors saying I need to specify a controller if no '/' is appended.  But I have tried adding this to no avail.  Plus I don't understand which controller it needs as I have tried specifying the controller this action is declared.

Can someone please have a look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 RenderingService pdfRenderingService


 def displayPDFSummary = {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: "_pdfTemplate", controller:"RSSCustomerOrder", model: [origSessionId:params.origSessionId])
        def fos= new FileOutputStream('NewTestFile.pdf')
          fos.write(bytes)
          fos.close()

        render(template: "_pdfTemplate", params: [origSessionId:params.origSessionId])
    }
```

I am getting the following error messages in the console:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.FileOutputStream.write() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream)

(Then prints contents of template...)

Possible solutions: write([B), write(int), write([B), write(int), wait(), wait(long)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the [FileOutputStream docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)? There's no write(OutputStream) method.

Try `fos.write(bytes.toByteArray())`.  Also, `bytes.writeTo(fos)` may work.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I really can't believe I didn't see it :(